# Using "Would not" for imaginary situation without "If"

Tags: grammar, irrealis-mood

I just saw this dialogue from video game (Witcher III) and wondering if this sentence is grammatically correct? and could someone please explain it.

> We are not done. It's yours, this gold. I would not want you to say you were inadequately compensated.

is the Would not in this context used for imaginary situation about future?

and what type of conditional sentence is this?

Comment: It's a kind of "distancing" device, often used to imply "formal, polite, respectful" attitudes or "hesitancy". Like asking ***Would you like** a cup of tea?* rather than ***Do you want** a cup of tea?* In your case, speaker could have said *I **do not** want you to say [I'm a cheapskate]*, but presumably he thought that would sound a bit too "blunt, forthright".

Comment: ...people talk about there being 3 (or 4, or ***more***) different types of "conditional" sentences, but I seriously doubt this specific usage falls into any of the main numbered categories you may be familiar with.